# JIT compile error with protobuf-net on MonoTouch/iOS device (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, protobuf-net, aot

I am using protobuf-net v2 beta r450 (binary distribution) and building a serialization assembly ahead of time using the technique described here:

http://www.frictionpointstudios.com/blog/2011/3/31/using-protobuf-net-serialization-in-unity-iphone.html

I create my serialization assembly on Windows and use it in my MonoTouch project. It works under the simulator. But when run on the device, where AOT compilation only is enforced, I get this error:

```
attempting to JIT compile method 'ProtoBuf.BufferPool.GetBuffer()' 
while running with --aot-only
```

The exception occurs when Serialize() is called:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(out_file))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, settings);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmmm... Very odd! I haven't seen that - it looks like AOT didnt spot the method is needed. I will have to investigate ways of making AOT believe that this is used.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I can create a ticket with Xamarin if nothing pops out at you.

Comment: It is at times like these I wish I still had convenient mac access

Comment: @t9mike please do open a bug report and include a small, self-contained test case so we can duplicate the issue. Some times we can avoid this exception (by reworking the class library) without having to change the user code. Thanks!

Comment: @poupou I submitted bug, http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1788. The sample is referenced in the ticket, but for others the direct link is https://github.com/t9mike/ProtoBuf1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grabbed the protobuf-net sources (v2 r470). Use of [ImmutableObject] was indeed one of the issues. I submitted a few minor patches to @MarcGravell via the protobuf-net issue list. I have updated my example at http://github.com/t9mike/ProtoBuf1 with this new assembly. Thanks everyone for the responses.

Comment: So it everything working fine now ? including "no more JIT error" ? the later *could* have been related to a bug in MonoTouch 5.0.1 (regression) that was fixed in 5.0.2.

Comment: Yes @poupou, my example runs fine on the device now. I am at MT 5.0.2. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost similar problem when working with unity (with protobuf-net and iOS), this helped me:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
```

Credit: https://github.com/antonholmquist/easy-serializer-unity